# Access one of the pages from two different paths in mobile app

Tags: mobile, flow

We have a feature in our mobile application that can be accessed from the main menu of the application. I it possible to access this page from another place of the application? Is that good or bad UX?

Answer (score 1):

*It's all right as long as there's a decent reason to have multiple flows leading to the same view.*

You can find an example on this page, e.g. the website tour page can be opened from the footer and one of the top right menus.

Such duplicates should be introduced with great caution since if there are too many it most likely indicates that there's an issue related to the website structure that makes too many duplicates necessary.